# Magento 2 Data migration error with catalog_eav_attribute

Tags: error, data-migration-tool

this is my first Magneto migration, so i need a little help. Migration stops and gives

> Record structure does not contain field layered_navigation_canonical

I check in database in m1 this field exist but in m2 not exist.To continuation migration I add code to ignore this field in **map.xml** and **map_eav.xml.dist** files

```
<ignore>
<field>catalog_eav_attribute.layered_navigation_canonical</field>
</ignore>
```

But still the same error. Hope someone to help.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new setup but our old database.

And Again the run the all migration commands :-

https://meetanshi.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

And Again same error found let me know .

Answer (score 0):

You need to **re-store the Database** and follow all steps of the **migrate:setting**